# Why MySQL 5.7 replication is verry slow on my new server

Tags: mysql, performance, replication

I have a problem with MySQL replication and I wanted to find advice or information on it.

Let me show you the infrastructure.

**Master:** This is our main MySQL server. I want to replace it by **Slave B**.

**Slave A**: This is our replication server connected to the **Master**. There are no issues with this server.

**Slave B**: This is our MySQL server that will replace the **Master**. For the moment this server is configured as replication to prepare the transfer.

**Goal:**
I have two MySQL Servers (**Master** / **Slave**) that work well. I want to replace our **Master** server with a new more efficient server (**Slave B**). To do this, we have set up a second **Slave B** replication to prepare for the transfer, but I have a problem with it. I tried to investigate the problem but I am not an expert on MySQL and I would like to ask for help to find the problem.

**PS:** I installed the **Percona Monitoring Management** and **sysbench** tools on **Slave B**. So if needed I can easily provide information from these tools to complete my post.

**Hardware detail of the machines:**

**Master:**

| **HOST** |  |
| --- | --- |
| Host OS | Xenserver |
| CPU | Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU D-1541 @ 2.10GHz |
| RAM on Host | 128 Go |
| Space on Host | RAID 10 SSD 4x744,687Go (1,454 TB) |
| **VM (MySQL)** |  |
| VM OS | Ubuntu 16.04 |
| RAM on VM | 120 Go |
| Space on VM | 1,3TB |

**SLAVE A**

| HOST |  |
| --- | --- |
| Host OS | Xenserver |
| CPU | Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v2 @ 2.60GHz |
| RAM on Host | 128 Go |
| Space on Host | RAID 1 HDD (2x2,728TB) 2,728TB |
| **VM (MySQL)** |  |
| VM OS | Ubuntu 16.04 |
| RAM on VM | 60 Go |
| Space on VM | 1,7TB |

**SLAVE B**

| HOST (MySQL) |  |
| --- | --- |
| Host OS | Ubuntu 18.04 |
| CPU | 2x Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4214R CPU @ 2.40GHz |
| RAM on Host | 192 Go |
| Space on Host | RAID 10 SSD (4x3,492TB) 6,984TB |

https://versus.com/en/intel-xeon-e5-2650-vs-intel-xeon-silver-4214r

**Observation of delays in replication:**

**Master:**

Master work on the file *mysql-bin.024080*

```
show master status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             File: mysql-bin.024080
         Position: 62186738
```

**Slave B:**

**Slave B** has all files (*mysql-bin.024080*) and it works on the file *mysql-bin.024075*. The gap between these files increases over time. Currently SQL_THREAD is behind 5 binary logs.

```
show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 10.55.55.21
                  Master_User: slave_replicator
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.024080
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 60111446
               Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.002952
                Relay_Log_Pos: 154669142
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.024075
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 154668929
              Relay_Log_Space: 2631436265
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 68158
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 195390
                  Master_UUID: 361633ab-6bb7-11e7-829c-1a76636a64a1
             Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Reading event from the relay log
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind: 
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB: 
                 Channel_Name: 
           Master_TLS_Version:
```

**Slave A:**

**Slave A** is up to date.

```
show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 10.55.55.21
                  Master_User: slave_replicator
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.024080
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 88327716
               Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.417046
                Relay_Log_Pos: 88327835
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.024080
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 88327716
              Relay_Log_Space: 88328255
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 195390
                  Master_UUID: 361633ab-6bb7-11e7-829c-1a76636a64a1
             Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind: 
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB: 
                 Channel_Name: 
           Master_TLS_Version: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

There are 3 ways that I identified

**1: MySQL configuration problem**
The many parameters of MySQL can influence server performance hence the importance of optimizing MySQL.
When I vary the *sync_binlog = 0* and *innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2* parameters the server performance improves greatly and allows the replication of **Slave B** to catch up. However, I want to leave *sync_binlog = 1* and *innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1*.
Do you know any other parameter that could influence the slowness of replication?

**2: Single-threaded CPU problem**
MySQL performs replication on a single process so only one CPU is engaged.
As the CPU of **Slave B** (2.40GHz) is slower than that of **Slave A** (2.60GHz).
The MySQL replication process on **Slave A** doesn’t have any problem with the workload whereas **Slave B** can’t support it.
How can I verify this ?

**3: Hardware problem**
A hardware problem can be considered. How can I find the bottleneck ?

[image]

It must be an I / O problem because the disk is busy on **Slave B**.
however the read write perfs looks bad?

```bash
ATOP - SLAVE B                               2021/01/28  19:07:53                               --------------                               10s elapsed
PRC |  sys    0.41s |  user   0.73s |  #proc    576 |  #trun      2 |  #tslpi   668  | #tslpu     2  | #zombie    0  | clones     0  | #exit      0  |
CPU |  sys       3% |  user      7% |  irq       0% |  idle   4722% |  wait     69%  | steal     0%  | guest     0%  | curf 1.97GHz  | curscal  56%  |
CPL |  avg1    1.86 |  avg5    1.67 |  avg15   1.79 |               |  csw    67549  |               | intr   28125  |               | numcpu    48  |
MEM |  tot   187.6G |  free  161.3G |  cache   5.7G |  buff  148.7M |  slab  716.4M  | shmem   0.5M  | vmbal   0.0M  | hptot   0.0M  | hpuse   0.0M  |
SWP |  tot   511.0M |  free  429.1M |               |               |                |               |               | vmcom 168.4G  | vmlim  94.3G  |
DSK |           sda |  busy     99% |  read     325 |  write   4319 |  KiB/r     16  | KiB/w     10  | MBr/s    0.5  | MBw/s    4.2  | avio 2.12 ms  |
NET |  transport    |  tcpi     359 |  tcpo     417 |  udpi       0 |  udpo       0  | tcpao      1  | tcppo      1  | tcprs      0  | udpie      0  |
NET |  network      |  ipi      364 |  ipo      345 |  ipfrw      0 |  deliv    362  |               |               | icmpi      3  | icmpo      0  |
NET |  enp61s0   0% |  pcki     132 |  pcko      81 |  sp   10 Gbps |  si   10 Kbps  | so   77 Kbps  | erri       0  | erro       0  | drpo       0  |
NET |  enp61s0   0% |  pcki     131 |  pcko     138 |  sp   10 Gbps |  si   72 Kbps  | so   55 Kbps  | erri       0  | erro       0  | drpo       0  |

  PID                   TID                  RDDSK                  WRDSK                  WCANCL                  DSK                 CMD         1/2
12588                     -                  5520K                 22508K                      0K                  99%                 mysqld
```

This is the SSD on my **SLAVE B** (Raid 10)
https://www.actualis.com/fr/sata/7075-intel-s4510-384tb-sata-6gb-s-3d-tlc-25-1dwpd-ssdsc2kb038t8.html

Comment: Additional information request. A set from SLAVE A and another set from SLAVE B, please. 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: What is the server_id on each machine?  How did you populate the data on the new Replica B?

Comment: After waiting 24 hours with the correct params (innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1 and sync_binlog = 1). You can find the results of the commands here.

SLAVE A
https://pastebin.com/5Qr2AQKi
https://pastebin.com/eyPYBSMB
https://pastebin.com/b5SEJfaD
https://pastebin.com/kjXsLA8i
https://pastebin.com/06rUfifF
https://pastebin.com/sZKG6kXa


SLAVE B
https://pastebin.com/pnVxjtBi
https://pastebin.com/f80JJb0u
https://pastebin.com/mqNTD5n2
https://pastebin.com/TAcAxypC
https://pastebin.com/EAeMj84D
https://pastebin.com/cQctdKhM

Comment: For the populate the data on my new replica B, I created a dump on MASTER with mysqldump then i imported it and activated the replication.
MASTER ID: 195390
SLAVE A ID: 194642
SLAVE B ID: 194643

Comment: Are the graphs above only from Slave B?  Thanks for posting your data. Analysis is in process.

Comment: Yes, I have the graphs only for this.

Answer (score 1):

I performed an IO test on **Slave B** to check if my problem comes from I/O. We can see that this result is much better than the previous one with only MySQL Replication.

Why I can't get the same I/O performance with MySQL ?

**ATOP with running fio**

````bash
$> fio --randrepeat=1 --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --gtod_reduce=1 --name=test --filename=test --bs=4k --iodepth=64 --size=2G --readwrite=randrw --rwmixread=75 --numjobs=1```

```bash
ATOP - SLAVE B                                   2021/02/01  09:07:29                                   --------------                                   10s elapsed
PRC | sys    1.14s  | user   1.04s |  #proc    587 | #trun      1  | #tslpi   680 |  #tslpu     0 |  #zombie    0 | clones     0  |              |  #exit      2 |
CPU | sys      10%  | user      6% |  irq       5% | idle   4780%  | wait      0% |               |  steal     0% | guest     0%  | curf 1.58GHz |  curscal  45% |
CPL | avg1    2.23  | avg5    5.91 |  avg15   5.57 |               |              |  csw   437791 |  intr  416652 |               |              |  numcpu    48 |
MEM | tot   187.6G  | free    3.2G |  cache  56.0G | buff  162.9M  | slab    2.2G |  shmem   0.7M |  shrss   0.0M | vmbal   0.0M  | hptot   0.0M |  hpuse   0.0M |
SWP | tot   511.0M  | free  429.3M |               |               |              |               |               |               | vmcom 168.4G |  vmlim  94.3G |
DSK |          sda  | busy     68% |  read  209257 | write  70808  | KiB/r      4 |  KiB/w      4 |  MBr/s   82.5 | MBw/s   27.7  | avq    63.06 |  avio 0.02 ms |
NET | transport     | tcpi     389 |  tcpo     555 | udpi       0  | udpo       0 |  tcpao      1 |  tcppo      1 | tcprs      0  | tcpie      0 |  udpie      0 |
NET | network       | ipi      392 |  ipo      385 | ipfrw      0  | deliv    391 |               |               |               | icmpi      2 |  icmpo      0 |
NET | enp61s0   0%  | pcki     188 |  pcko     234 | sp   10 Gbps  | si   13 Kbps |  so  243 Kbps |  erri       0 | erro       0  | drpi       0 |  drpo       0 |
NET | enp61s0   0%  | pcki      20 |  pcko      47 | sp   10 Gbps  | si    1 Kbps |  so   50 Kbps |  erri       0 | erro       0  | drpi       0 |  drpo       0
````

**ATOP on Slave B with running MySQL**

```bash
ATOP - Slave B                  2021/02/03  08:16:50                  --------------                    10s elapsed
PRC | sys    0.55s |  user   0.71s | #proc    573 | #tslpi   785  | #tslpu     2 | #zombie    0  | #exit      1 |
CPU | sys       5% |  user      6% | irq       0% | idle   4738%  | wait     52% | curf 1.90GHz  | curscal  54% |
CPL | avg1    2.94 |  avg5    2.26 | avg15   1.82 | csw    85384  | intr   34355 |               | numcpu    48 |
MEM | tot   187.6G |  free   92.5G | cache  72.4G | buff  178.5M  | slab    2.7G | vmbal   0.0M  | hptot   0.0M |
SWP | tot   511.0M |  free  429.5M |              |               |              | vmcom 169.3G  | vmlim  94.3G |
DSK |          sda |  busy     99% | read     727 | write   4837  | MBr/s    1.1 | MBw/s    5.9  | avio 1.78 ms |
NET | transport    |  tcpi    1232 | tcpo    1284 | udpi       0  | udpo       0 | tcpao      2  | tcppo      2 |
NET | network      |  ipi     1236 | ipo     1208 | ipfrw      0  | deliv   1234 | icmpi      2  | icmpo      0 |
NET | enp61s0   0% |  pcki    1019 | pcko    1002 | sp   10 Gbps  | si  508 Kbps | so  105 Kbps  | erro       0 |
NET | enp61s0   0% |  pcki     121 | pcko      78 | sp   10 Gbps  | si    9 Kbps | so   77 Kbps  | erro       0 |
```

**ATOP on Master with running MySQL**

```bash
ATOP - Master                      2021/02/03  08:13:07                      ------                       10s elapsed
PRC | sys    2.75s  | user   9.46s  | #proc    313  | #tslpi   468 |  #tslpu     1 |  #zombie    0 |  #exit      0 |
CPU | sys      23%  | user     89%  | irq       1%  | idle   2820% |  wait     68% |  curf 2.10GHz |  curscal   ?% |
CPL | avg1    2.65  | avg5    2.51  | avg15   1.74  | csw   114254 |  intr  111525 |               |  numcpu    30 |
MEM | tot   117.6G  | free  540.8M  | cache  83.6M  | dirty   0.0M |  buff  125.8M |  slab  316.8M |               |
SWP | tot   120.0G  | free  100.6G  |               |              |               |  vmcom 121.2G |  vmlim 178.8G |
PAG | scan   62526  | stall      0  |               |              |  swin   13616 |               |  swout  13017 |
LVM | master--vg-root  | busy     48%  | read   17477  | write   1580 |  MBr/s  27.30 |  MBw/s   0.65 |  avio 0.25 ms |
LVM | a--vg-swap_1  | busy     31%  | read   13617  | write  13017 |  MBr/s   5.32 |  MBw/s   5.08 |  avio 0.12 ms |
DSK |         xvda  | busy     61%  | read   30832  | write   2685 |  MBr/s  32.62 |  MBw/s   5.74 |  avio 0.18 ms |
NET | transport     | tcpi    7823  | tcpo    7678  | udpi       2 |  udpo       2 |  tcpao      1 |  tcppo    385 |
NET | network       | ipi     7825  | ipo     6857  | ipfrw      0 |  deliv   7825 |  icmpi      0 |  icmpo      0 |
NET | eth0    ----  | pcki    7829  | pcko    6858  | si  984 Kbps |  so 2202 Kbps |  erri       0 |  erro       0 |
```

Comment: Which server and at what appx date/time produced this data and what was the request at the Command Line?

Comment: I run this command at 10h on Slave B: ```bash fio --randrepeat=1 --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --gtod_reduce=1 --name=test --filename=test --bs=4k --iodepth=64 --size=2G --readwrite=randrw --rwmixread=75 --numjobs=1 ```

Comment: Could you share ATOP Master report similar to the ATOP SLAVE B of a few days ago?

Comment: I added the information in the answer above.

Comment: Thanks for the ATOP of MASTER dated 2021/02/03 08:13.  Significant differences from SLAVE B to MASTER include, A) MEM 70G less  B) cache 55G less  C) slab 2G less D) SWP 119G more E) vmcom 47G less F) vmlim 84G more probably all contribute to 'slower' processing on MASTER.  I will request Additional info from MASTER for workload analysis in a minute.

Comment: Additional information from MASTER request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: I use SSD RAID 10 on MASTER. You can find the results of the commands here: https://pastebin.com/JBG7ZSh5 
https://pastebin.com/ax1p6WJs 
https://pastebin.com/qV2cKehU 
https://pastebin.com/QCCcpdm0

Answer (score 0):

Rate per second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your Slave B my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function every second
innodb_log_buffer_size=1G  # from 16M for ~ 30 minutes in RAM before write to media
innodb_io_capacity=1500  # from 200 to enable higher IOPS to your SSD storage
read_rnd_buffer_size=128K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 6,753
```

For additional suggestions view profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.

There are many more opportunities to improve speed of processing with Slave B.

Comment: I try update MySQL with this config but that does not solve the problem.

Comment: When you are ready to dig deeper we are here for you.  Our free Utility Script findfragtables.sql may target your need to OPTIMIZE tables to improve performance.  On SLAVE B, SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%pages_dirty%' would reveal there are more than 300,000 dirty pages that have built over time.  Our analysis for your Top 20 Global Variable Suggestions would help you get that number manageable and reduce overhead for the instance,

Comment: ```SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%pages_dirty%';
+--------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                  | Value |
+--------------------------------+-------+
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty | 3894  |
+--------------------------------+-------+```

Comment: Have the suggestions of 01/27/2021 at 20:39 been applied to SLAVE B?  Possibly overnight SLAVE B could get 300,000 pages flushed to the tables out of change-area.

Comment: Yes, the suggestions has been applied to SLAVE B. I can remove the setting to see if the number of pages_dirty increases.

Comment: If your SLAVE B is keeping up, I would recommend analysis again in 90-120 days.  If not, let's Skype Talk, please.

Comment: @jcrespeau If any comments or Answers are helpful, you now have enough reputation to upvote or Accept answers that have been helpful in your journey. We would like to know if we have been of any value.  Welcome to SE.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your MASTER my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% CPU cycles used for function every SECOND
innodb_buffer_pool_size=96G  # from ~ 110G for ~ 80 percent limit of available RAM
open_files_limit=64K  # from 1024 to enable using more ulimit Open Files capacity of 102400 that exist today, per the ulimit -a report posted.
innodb_open_files=32K  # from 400 to reduce opened_tables RPS of 179
table_open_cache=32K  # from 400 - should always be equal to innodb_open_files
```

Observation, select_scan RPS of 46 can be minimized with appropriate indexes after analysis of Slow Query Log.  long_query_time of 1 second vs 10 seconds would document your slow queries.

This is just the beginning of suggestions to improve processing capacity.  View our profile, Network profile for contact information, and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.